# Python/Selenium Can't find searchbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to select the first searchbox on this website:
https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Bundesrecht/

This is my code:

```
   for ii in testList2:
    varTitel = ii

    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_SuchworteField')
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_SuchworteField"]/span')
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_name('MainContent_SuchworteField_Value')

    searchBox.send_keys(varTitel)
    searchBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(1)
    print("Query link: " + driver.current_url)
    driver.back()

driver.quit()
```

As you can see, I tried three ways of selecting the searchbox. Everytime I am getting NoSuchElement exceptions.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"MainContent_SuchworteField"}

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="MainContent_SuchworteField"]/span"}

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"MainContent_SuchworteField_Value"}
```

Here is a snippet of what is being shown after inspecting the site.
[image]

I hope you can help me,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work with the following code. I used the Chrome webdriver, but I think using sleep and giving the page more time to load may do it for you. I apologize, I know this isn't an answer with your code, but it does show the xpath will work.Note that the xpath is slightly different than yours. Otherwise, I trust someone on here may be able to produce a better answer. Hope it helps!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Bundersrecht/')

sleep(5)

suchworte = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_SuchworteField_Value"]')

suchworte.send_keys('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot of the *HTML* you have provided to identify the `<input>` field next to the field with text as **Suchworte** you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Bundesrecht/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='MainContent_SuchworteField_Value']").send_keys("Sasa")
```

Browser Snapshot :

[image: Sasa]